# Getting Client IP from Node.js behind Stingray load balancer

Tags: node.js, express, load-balancing

We're running multiple node instances behind a stingray load balancer.  Our node.js applications run Express.js.  When we access `req.connection.remoteAddress` it returns the IP of our stingray appliance.

Does anyone know how to forward the client IP?

Thank you!

Comment: See if there are other values in the request where the load balancer passed the original IP address. For example, sometimes is comes under HTTP_TRUE_CLIENT_IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided this information isn't out of date, the X-Cluster-Client-Ip header should contain the original ip.

```
var remoteAddress = req.header('X-Cluster-Client-Ip');
```

Other options are referenced here:

http://community.riverbed.com/t5/Articles/IP-Transparency-with-Stingray-software-04-12-2006/td-p/22646

Answer (score 0):

The link in the accepted answer doesn't work anymore, so just to add that if you enable the Transparency option at the Stingray level then the request will look to the backend like it's from the original IP rather than the load balancer. That way you can avoid pulling it from other environment variables, and avoid possibly having to deal with multiple 'original' IPs in a variable.

The 'transparent' option is in the Connection Management properties of a pool.